# how to get output as "select * from employee" ,"select * from salaries","select * from student" and "select * from attendance"

Tags: java, mysql

package array;

public class A {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = { "employee","salaries","student","attendance"};
    for (String x : arr)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }


}
```

}
//output:
employee
salaries
student
attendance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system.out.println line is missing the description that you are expecting. You need to add the statement for it to print. Below is the edited code.

```
package array;

public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = { "employee","salaries","student","attendance"};
    for (String x : arr)
    {
        System.out.println("Select * from "+x);  // you need to edit this line
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your System.out.println to

```
System.out.println("select * from " + x);
```